# Count number of numbers in a single cell

Tags: excel, count, numbers

I want to count the number of numbers in a single cell.

Example:

In cell A1, I have the following addition:

`=12+45+23+51+10` which totals (and shows) `141`.

In cell B1, I would like the see how many numbers have been added together, which means that there should be 5 (12 is a number, 45 another one, etc... and all together, there are 5 numbers in cell A1).

I know it seems to be a ridiculous question, but I scanned all the platforms for this issue and did not find any suitable solution. Tried all the `LEN` and `LEN SUBSTITUTE` alternatives out there, but somehow it does not work.

Thank you upfront for your help. Optimal solution would be a excel formula, alternatively VBA would also work.

Comment: Count the number of operators and add one. to get the formula you need to use formulatext which is contained in an excel addin http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/formulatext-function-HA102753280.aspx  or you have to use some vba: http://dmcritchie.mvps.org/excel/formula.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excel 2013 has a new function `Formulatext()` which returns the, well, formula text. Using that the `Len()` and `Substitute()` approach works.

```
=LEN(FORMULATEXT(A1))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(FORMULATEXT(A1),"+",""))+1
```

[image]

Comment: Please don't insult people who edit your posts, however old the post might be. The edit is objectively good, and the age of your post doesn't matter when it comes to improving the content on the site.

Answer (score 2):

Hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> and Insert -> Module with the following VBA:

```
Function NumCount(Rng As Range)
x = Split(Rng.Formula, "+")
NumCount = UBound(x) + 1
End Function
```

Then you can call `=NumCount(A1)` on any cell to get the number of numbers in the formula for that cell.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this without using a **User Defined Function (UDF)** written in Excel VBA. Something like this should work:

```
Public Function numsAdded(cell1 As Range)
    Dim formulaString As String
    formulaString = cell1.Formula
    numsAdded = Len(formulaString) - Len(Replace(formulaString, "+", "")) + 1
End Function
```

Once you've added that to a VBA module, you can use it as a function in any cell in your spreadsheet.

> ***Edit:*** Apparently there *is* a way if you have Excel 2013, as [@teylyn suggests in the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26108011/3025856). If you use Excel 2010 or earlier, like me, you'll still need VBA.

Answer (score 0):

Use this VBA:

```vb
Function GetFormula(Cell as Range) as String
   GetFormula = Cell.Formula
End Function
```

and then to get the number of numbers...

```
=LEN(GetFormula(D99))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(GetFormula(D99),"+",""))
```

on this as my D99 contents...

```
=45+46+47+50+100
```

[image]

The one major drawback here is that I'm assuming everything is `+`; if you have `-`, `*`, `/` or other operators this gets more challenging.  You might be able to use replace for each, but you'd always be limited to the four basic operators. If someone used exponents or mod, this would be harder.

Answer (score 0):

Also possible in earlier Excel versions without VBA - subject to (i) there is always at least one value in the cells, (ii) the operator is always `+` and (iii) the cells are in a column.

Replace `=` with `'=` in that column, apply the substitution, say:

```
=LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"+",""))+1
```

in a different column and Paste Special, Value the results for that other column. Then apply Text To Columns on the original column with `'` as the delimiter.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
=LEN(SUBSTITUTE(F16,"+","+"))
```

***Note:*** F16 is only an example name for the cell you want to do the counting on.

Example:

```
F16=45+65+76 # Gives 186
F17=LEN(SUBSTITUTE(F16,"+","+")) # Gives 3
```

Comment: and if F16 contains 45+46+47+48 it still returns 3.  Len and substitute are operating on the result 186 not the formula.

Comment: You are absolutely right. But if you copy F16 and paste (as text) the cell with the summation to another cell, it works.

Comment: Apparently in some versions of spreadsheets, pasting as a text (just keeping the formula instead of getting the resulting value), doesn't work. So you can ignore that completley, but something like Gettheformula function as teylyn explained up there can do the trick.